# Paperclip Image URL trailing fingerprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, fancybox, paperclip

I am using a Rails app in hand with AngularJS, in addition I am using FancyBox with the application. AngularJS is having trouble loading the images within FancyBox because URL to said image has a trailing fingerprint in this format:

```
                                                                  v This.
"/system/photos/images/000/000/006/original/Screenshot_%281%29.png?1444087540"
```

This happens when I call Object.image.url. The image file itself has no trailing fingerprint.

My Paperclip setup is completely default. I am having trouble figuring out how to disable this trailing fingerprint after the file extension, it does not seem to be clearly called out in the documentation.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url() function accepts a parameter to disable this:

```
url(default_style, timestamp: false)
```

When in doubt about functionality always look at the source for the gem or the [docs for the function](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip%2FAttachment%3Aurl).

Comment: Thank you! This does seem to be what I need. Call me ignorant, but how do I set this in an initializer?

Comment: I figured it out! To set this in an initializer you just need to modify Paperclip's default_options like this: 

    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false